# Replacing a file with another file but keeping the file the same name.

Tags: c++, visual-c++, file-io, mfc, overwrite

My programming knowlege is very limited so please take this into account when reading this. I am using Visual C++ MFC and I am looking for a basic function that would overwrite the contents of a file but keep the file the same name. I am sure this is probably fairly simple however I can't seem to find anything online. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have a look at `CFile::modeCreate` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cz0a83sb(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: As usual, here are many ways to do this but perhaps the simplest is to delete the first file and rename the second.

Comment: Where is the content coming from? Are you saving some input from the application or are you copying the contents of another file into the one to keep?

Comment: Right this is for a MMI where the background is set to a bitmap called "mainscreen.bmp" however I have a folder with various other bitmaps. What happens so far is that I load a listbox of all the available bitmaps. The next step I want to achieve is selecting one of these bitmaps and overwriting the contents "mainscreen.bmp" with the bitmap I have selected.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [CFile::Open()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hwbccf8z%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) there is flags to specify to open an existing file without truncating it. For example if you want to create the file if it not exists, or using the alreading existing without truncating you can use `CFile::modeCreate|CFile::modeNoTruncate`. You can then seet to the needed position by using [CFile::Seek()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/8c5ccz0x%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've done any MFC work so I'll just give you the general standard on how to do this in C/C++. This will give you a direction on how to work with MFC.

When you're opening a file, you can choose an "open flag" that tells the file system how to open it. it can be "a" for append, "r" for read, "w" for write over (trunacte), and you can add "b" if it's a binary file.

so to do that just do:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("my_file.whatever", "wb"); 
if (fp) 
{ 
    //now write to
    the file... ....

    fclose(fp); 
}
```